# Насколько протокол CAS подходит для работы с REST-API?

Tags: java, spring, безопасность

Простая ситуация. Допустим есть несколько приложений:

```
user.war      // frontend
admin.war     // frontend
portal.war    // frontend
rest-api.war  // REST API
```

... которым нужен SSO, для того чтобы пользователь мог, единожды авторизовавшись, работать с ними всеми с соответствующими ACL. В клиентских приложениях по сути нет ничего кроме JS кода, они обращаются к API и отображают полученные данные.

Так вот CAS хорошо работает между клиентскими приложениями. Ну потому что те поддерживают HTTP редиректы. Что касается работы с REST, то тут все сложнее. У меня впечатление, что авторы CAS про REST и stateless вообще никогда не слышали.

Насколько можно понять из обрывочной документации, для того чтобы использовать CAS для REST API придумали PGT. Т.е. одно из фронтенд приложений должно выступить в роли прокси для API. [Во-ооот такой будет Web Flow](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/cas-server-documentation/protocol/CAS-Protocol.md#proxy-web-flow-diagram).
При этом само фронтенд приложение тоже может быть за reverse прокси, и тогда прокси будет уже два. И самое главное, если фронтенд приложений несколько, то неизвестно в каком из них авторизовался пользователь.

В связи с чем вопрос: для вышеуказанного юзкейса вы бы что посоветовали использовать или использовали на продакшене? Или может я все не так понял и CAS на самом деле хороший.

Comment: Попадаются заметки, что всё работает замечательно. После небольшой доработки напильником.

Comment: @Sergey Да, уже разобрался, что там к чему. Оно не может не работать. Потому что прокси для обращения из фронтенда к REST API надо писать самому :) В отличие от OAuth2, например, для которого есть реализация API Gateway в Spring Cloud. Я думаю это и будет решающим фактором, поскольку Jasig CAS нестабилен (2 бага поймал), перегружен лишними функциями, и его WEB UI сразу идет на помойку, благодаря "гениальному" решению разработчиков брать все JS библиотеки через CDN. В то время как OAuth2 провайдер поднимается из Spring Boot за 30 минут. Есть еще правда SAML, но он выглядит как говно мамонта.

Comment: Такой сервер http://keycloak.jboss.org/ хороший?

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо! Да, хорошая документация + скринкасты + демо + standalone версия. Надо будет попробовать поиграться.